# How to convert NetCDF file (.nc) containing multilevel modeling data to .csv file using R?

Tags: r, excel, csv, netcdf, multi-level

I am working on a NetCDF file where there is multi level of model data in my .nc file. It is my goal to convert it into .csv or .txt file that i can read it through Excel. I am following this website's instruction http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog607/Rmd/netCDF_01.htm.

It's for single level data model, but I want to use this code for 2 or more level of data and I am getting the .csv file too after done some R operation but whatever I am getting it's not showing the actual results, there is some fraction difference of temperature between my achieving result and the actual result. I am using this R code for my multi level modeling.

```
>library(chron)
> library(RColorBrewer)
> library(lattice)
> library(ncdf4)

> getwd()
[1] "/Users/arnob_t78"
> workdir <- "/Users/arnob_t78/Angelika"
> setwd(workdir)

> ncname <- "60_59"
> ncfname <- paste(ncname, ".nc", sep = "")
> dname1 <- "t"
> ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
> print(ncin)
File 60_59.nc (NC_FORMAT_64BIT):

 1 variables (excluding dimension variables):
    short t[longitude,latitude,level,time]   
        scale_factor: 0.00097129842383799
        add_offset: 262.636706123249
        _FillValue: -32767
        missing_value: -32767
        units: K
        long_name: Temperature
        standard_name: air_temperature

 4 dimensions:
    longitude  Size:97
        units: degrees_east
        long_name: longitude
    latitude  Size:55
        units: degrees_north
        long_name: latitude
    level  Size:2
        long_name: model_level_number
    time  Size:155   *** is unlimited ***
        units: hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:0.0
        long_name: time
        calendar: gregorian

2 global attributes:
    Conventions: CF-1.6
    history: 2016-03-16 17:53:56 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-1.14.5: grib_to_netcdf /data/data01/scratch/_mars-atls00-    95e2cf679cd58ee9b4db4dd119a05a8d-BfvdSl.grib -o /data/data01/scratch/_grib2netcdf-atls09-95e2cf679cd58ee9b4db4dd119a05a8d-M7sA4v.nc -utime

> lon <- ncvar_get(ncin, "longitude")
> nlon <- dim(lon)
> head(lon)
[1] -27.00 -26.25 -25.50 -24.75 -24.00 -23.25

> lat <- ncvar_get(ncin, "latitude")
> nlat <- dim(lat)
> head(lat)
[1] 73.50 72.75 72.00 71.25 70.50 69.75

> level <- ncvar_get(ncin, "level")
> nlevel <- dim(level)
> head(level)
[1] 59 60

> t <- ncvar_get(ncin, "time")
> tunits <- ncatt_get(ncin, "time", "units")
> nt <- dim(t)
> head(t)
[1] 973014 973038 973062 973086 973110 973134

> print(c(nlon, nlat, nlevel, nt))
[1]  97  55   2 155

> tmp.array1 <- ncvar_get(ncin, dname1)
> dlname1 <- ncatt_get(ncin, dname1, "long_name")
> dunits1 <- ncatt_get(ncin, dname1, "units")
> fillvalue <- ncatt_get(ncin, dname1, "_FillValue")
> dim(tmp.array1)
[1]  97  55   2 155

> title <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "title")
> institution <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "institution")
> datasource <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "source")
> references <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "references")
> history <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "history")
> conventions <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "Conventions")

> tmp.vec.long1 <- as.vector(tmp.array1)
> length(tmp.vec.long1)
[1] 1653850

> tmp.mat1 <- matrix(tmp.vec.long1, nrow = nlon * nlat, ncol = nlevel)
> dim(tmp.mat1)
[1] 5335    2

> head(na.omit(tmp.mat1)) 
     [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 254.3496 254.5176
[2,] 253.5764 253.7066
[3,] 252.9684 252.4604
[4,] 252.6692 250.9879
[5,] 252.7304 249.6252
[6,] 253.1054 248.7433

> tlonlat1 <- expand.grid(t,lon, lat)
> tmp.df02t <- data.frame(cbind(tlonlat1, tmp.mat1))
> names(tmp.df02t) <- c("t", "lon", "lat", "t59", "t60")
> head(na.omit(tmp.df02t, 20))
       t lon  lat      t59      t60
1 973014 -27 73.5 254.3496 254.5176
2 973038 -27 73.5 253.5764 253.7066
3 973062 -27 73.5 252.9684 252.4604
4 973086 -27 73.5 252.6692 250.9879
5 973110 -27 73.5 252.7304 249.6252
6 973134 -27 73.5 253.1054 248.7433

> csvfile <- "60_59_data.csv"
> write.table(na.omit(tmp.df02t), csvfile, row.names = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

The problem is after done operating R code the values i am achieving on t59 and t60 its not actually the exact result, there is a fraction between range -10 to 20 kelvin of temperature. Can you just tell me what i am missing or doing wrong? I hope you can understand the scenario.

Here is some images which shows what i have done in R and the sample results.

[i guess here i am missing something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AoWf.png)

Comment: It seems to be an issue of precision. Refer to this documentation https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ncdf4/ncdf4.pdf which has several mentions of precision settings and fix your code accordingly.

Comment: Can you please give an example or anything? @warmoverflow

Comment: Please give some examples of what your source data look like and the output with reduced precision look like.

Comment: @warmoverflow i updated my post and now can you understand the scenario that what i am doing wrong?

Comment: It is still not clear what are the expected results. Is t59 suppose to be identical to t60, or is t59 suppose to be identical across all rows, or if not, what exact results you expect to see here?

Comment: @warmoverflow i am expecting the results like as - after done calculating the values of t59 and t60 should be                                                                                 t lon  lat      t59      t60
973014 -27 73.5 254.3496 254.5176
973038 -27 73.5 253.5764 253.7066

Comment: t59 and t60 are independent data according to right time, longitude and latitude

Comment: I am confused. Isn't this expected values exactly the same as you have in your output?

Comment: @warmoverflow nope, that is the problem i am facing actually! The problem is after done operating R code the values i am achieving on t59 and t60 its not actually the exact result, because it have also the result excel sheet for this 60_59.xls where i can compare the results of mine what is getting here and what in there. so there is a fraction between range -10 to 20 kelvin of temperature.